# Obtaining a series expansion for an integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to obtain a series expansion for the integral 
$\int_0^{1/2} dx/(1+x^4)$ 
So far I used the fact for a Geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$ if $\lvert{r}\rvert<1$
and replaced $r$ with $-x^4$ and got $\frac{1}{1+x^4} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{4k}$ if $\lvert{x}\rvert<1$

I am kind of unsure if this is even an answer or that if I need to go down a different path in order to solve this problem. If someone could tell me what to do in addition to this or what to differently or just show me how to do these types of problems it would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Now just integrate term-by-term.

Comment: $@T.Bongers$ so do I just integrate the right hand side of my equation for the sum then index my integrated sum from 0 to .5?

Comment: The series starts at $k=0$, but just integrate term by term as T. Bongers suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach us fine.

Integrating term-by-term, your integral equals
$$\sum_{n\ge\color{red}{0}}\frac{(-1)^k}{4k+1}\frac1{2^{4k+1}}$$

I doubt if a nice closed form exists...

Comment: Actually, the integral is equal to $$\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{17} \left(20 \sqrt{2}+33\right)\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(12 \sqrt{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, I get the same thing by simple but a bit tedious partial fraction decomposition, and confirmed by some antiderivative calculator. But I think that’s not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Nope, but you said you doubt a nice closed-form exists.  I was just correcting that.

Comment: @RonGordon Well, maybe we misunderstood each other. I somehow think this closed form isn’t nice enough, especially for such simple integral. If this closed form is a result of 3-page long contour integration, that’s brilliant.

Comment: It is a closed form so long as the effort to compute it is significantly less than the effort to perform a numerical integration of the integral, for the same precision.  With simple trig and log functions, this is usually the case.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a side comment.*

Considering $$\int_0^a \frac{dx}{1+x^4}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{a^{4k+1}}{4k+1}$$ it could be intersting to know in advance the number $n$ of terms to be summed in order to have $p$ significant correct figures.

This being said means that we want to know $n$ such that 
$$\frac{a^{4n+5}}{4n+5}\leq 10^{-p}$$ The solution for the equality is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and write
$$n=-\frac{5}{4}-\frac{W\left(-10^p \log (a)\right)}{4 \log (a)}$$ and we shall  use $\lceil n\rceil$ for the calculations.

If, as in your case, $a<1$, we face a large argument, we can evaluate the value of Lambert function using the expansion given in the Wikipedia linked page
$$W(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

The table below shows the results for various $p$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \lceil n\rceil & \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(4k+1)\,2^{4k+1}} \\
 1 & 0 & 0.50000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 0 & 0.50000000000000000000 \\
 3 & 1 & 0.49375000000000000000 \\
 4 & 2 & 0.49396701388888888889 \\
 5 & 2 & 0.49396701388888888889 \\
 6 & 3 & 0.49395762386485042735 \\
 7 & 4 & 0.49395807265276403029 \\
 8 & 5 & 0.49395804994623268729 \\
 9 & 6 & 0.49395805113832558279 \\
 10 & 6 & 0.49395805113832558279 \\
 11 & 7 & 0.49395805107409643972 \\
 12 & 8 & 0.49395805107762417674 \\
 13 & 9 & 0.49395805107742752924 \\
 14 & 10 & 0.49395805107743862064 \\
 15 & 10 & 0.49395805107743862064 \\
 16 & 11 & 0.49395805107743798904 \\
 17 & 12 & 0.49395805107743802530 \\
 18 & 13 & 0.49395805107743802320 \\
 19 & 14 & 0.49395805107743802332 \\
 20 & 14 & 0.49395805107743802332
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For $a=\frac 12$, quick and dirty linear regressions give
$$n=0.779\,p-1.836 \qquad \text{and} \qquad p= 1.283\, n+2.362$$ showing, as  robjohn commented, that *"there should be approximately $1.2$ digits added for each term in the series"*.

Comment: There should be approximately $1.2$ digits added for each term in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete Beta Function
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^4}
&=\frac14\int_0^{1/16}\frac{x^{-3/4}\,\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\operatorname{B}\left(\frac1{17};\frac14,\frac34\right)}
\end{align}
$$
Partial Fractions with $\alpha^2=i$; i.e. $\alpha=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$ and $\alpha^3=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^4}
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac12\left(\frac1{1-i^3x^2}+\frac1{1-ix^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac14\left(\frac1{1-\alpha^3x}+\frac1{1+\alpha^3x}+\frac1{1-\alpha x}+\frac1{1+\alpha x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{4\alpha^3}\int_0^{\alpha^3/2}\left(\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\frac1{4\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha/2}\left(\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{4\alpha^3}\log\left(\frac{1+\alpha^3/2}{1-\alpha^3/2}\right)+\frac1{4\alpha}\log\left(\frac{1+\alpha/2}{1-\alpha/2}\right)\\
&=\frac{-1-i}{4\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{2\sqrt2-1+i}{2\sqrt2+1-i}\right)+\frac{1-i}{4\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{2\sqrt2+1+i}{2\sqrt2-1-i}\right)\\
&=\frac1{4\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{5+2\sqrt2}{5-2\sqrt2}\right)
+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}3\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\log\left(\frac{33+20\sqrt2}{17}\right)+\arctan\left(12\sqrt2\right)}{4\sqrt2}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is pure beauty !